# Why screen no signal only on first boot? how to fix?

Tags: windows-7, boot, display, signal

Every day is the same. I arrive to the room, I turn on the PC, screen no signal. If I shut down the PC and boot again, the signal recovers, until the next boot hours later. I've had this problem for months, today it happened two times in a row for the first time. When the "no signal" is showing, I disconnect and reconnect the screen, but the problem persist. I have to shut down and re-boot to have signal. I use Windows 7 Ultimate.

I've found other topics related with the *no signal* problem, but to me it only happens on first boot, which is very baffling.

Why might this be occuring? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I would check your video card, if its prebuilt, I would consult the manufacturer, it seems to be some error in your gpu. I would also  check the connection on your monitor,if your using a analog video signal, like vga, i would check your cable. And if all fails, try a quick virus scan.